# i386 GNU ld: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, osdev

I'm working my way through [The Little Book About OS Development](https://littleosbook.github.io/#the-framebuffer), specifically the section on the framebuffer (linked). I'm able to successfully assemble, link, turn into an ISO file and boot pure assembly, but as soon as I try to link a compiled object file for my C code (called from my loader, which was written in assembly), the linker complains. Here's the output:

```
nasm -f elf loader.s -o loader.o
nasm -f elf out.s -o out.o
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@6/6.4.0/bin/gcc-6 -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c  framebuffer.c -o framebuffer.o
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@6/6.4.0/bin/gcc-6 -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c  kmain.c -o kmain.o
i386-unknown-linux-gnu-ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 loader.o out.o framebuffer.o kmain.o -o kernel.elf
framebuffer.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
make: *** [kernel.elf] Error 1
```

I'm on a Mac, so as you can tell I've compiled a custom version of the GNU linker so that I can use linker scripts, and I've made sure to specify GCC 6 (the system default is 4.0). Anyway, here's my Makefile:

```
OBJECTS = loader.o out.o framebuffer.o kmain.o
CC = /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@6/6.4.0/bin/gcc-6
CFLAGS = -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector \
-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c
LDFLAGS = -T link.ld -melf_i386
AS = nasm
ASFLAGS = -f elf

all: kernel.elf

kernel.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    i386-unknown-linux-gnu-ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o kernel.elf

os.iso: kernel.elf
    cp kernel.elf iso/boot/kernel.elf
    mkisofs -R                          \
        -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito    \
        -no-emul-boot                   \
        -boot-load-size 4               \
        -A os                           \
        -input-charset utf8             \
        -quiet                          \
        -boot-info-table                \
        -o os.iso                       \
        iso

run: os.iso
    bochs -f bochsrc.txt -q

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< -o $@

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o kernel.elf os.iso
```

Here's my linker script:

```
ENTRY(loader)                /* the name of the entry label */

SECTIONS {
. = 0x00100000;          /* the code should be loaded at 1 MB */

.text ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
{
*(.text)             /* all text sections from all files */
}

.rodata ALIGN (0x1000) : /* align at 4 KB */
{
*(.rodata*)          /* all read-only data sections from all files */
}

.data ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
{
*(.data)             /* all data sections from all files */
}

.bss ALIGN (0x1000) :    /* align at 4 KB */
{
*(COMMON)            /* all COMMON sections from all files */
*(.bss)              /* all bss sections from all files */
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your version of GCC6 an OSX one? Maybe it is generating macho objects that the i386 LD doesn't understand. What does the command `file framebuffer.o` show. You may find yourself having to create a GCC cross compiler (like i686-elf-gcc) and use it to compile.

Comment: Yeah, apparently so. I thought using `-m32` to make it an i386 object file would be enough, but apparently it's still a Mach-O object. Thank you!

Comment: No `-m32` only generates 32-bit code. If on a 64-bit OS/X it will default to 64-bit code (`-m64`). No problem

Comment: This helped (I think) but now I'm having another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621305/cross-compiling-for-elf-i386-instruction-requires-not-64bit-mode-os-developmen

Comment: the parameter `-nostdlib` is a linker parameter not a compiler parameter.

Comment: the parameter `-nodefaultlibs` is a linker parameter not a compiler parameter

Comment: the parameter `-nostartfiles` is a linker parameter not a compiler parameter

Comment: you might want to use: `objdmp -f framebuffer.o` to get the details of how the file: `framebuffer.o` is actually formatted

Comment: Thanks for the `objdmp` tip, but I already know enough about what the format of the file is. Also, the options you listed are linker options, but GCC accepts linker options for compiling: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html.

Comment: in the Makefile, when defining the macros, suggest using `:=` rather than `=` so the macro definition is only evaluated once rather than each time it is referenced

Comment: Yes, the compile step ignores linker options.  But the linker step needs those options

Comment: So I should move them to LDFLAGS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156172/discussion-between-christopher-dumas-and-user3629249).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was solved by cross-compiling GNU Binutils and GCC together (with the same prefix) on my Mac. I did this according to the instructions [here](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~nakazato/tips/xgcc.html).